# Is it good idea to remove dash from a GUID?

Tags: c#, asp.net, guid

I have code which replaces the dash with empty strings in a GUID.

```
Replace(System.Guid.NewGuid.ToString, "-", "")
```

Would that remove the uniqueness of the guid?

Also can someone confirm this too?

We are storing GUIDs in our database as char(32). Is that okay? Because we have international users in different timezone, we're concerned that the character length could go over 32. Thanks.

Comment: Just like that, did you know that instead of replacing the '-' char, you use the ToString of the Guid? Simply use the N format: System.Guid.NewGuid.ToString("N")

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, it is OK to remove the dashes.  The uniqueness of the Guid is guaranteed.

Dashes are only for readability: internally the Guid is made of 16 bytes.
You can see [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373931(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID) for more details.
Take a look at constructors too:

```
public Guid(int a, short b, short c, byte[] d);
public Guid(int a, short b, short c, byte d, 
            byte e, byte f, byte g, byte h, 
            byte i, byte
public Guid(uint a, ushort b, ushort c, byte d, 
            byte e, byte f, byte g, byte h, 
            byte i, byte j, byte k);
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back we are storing a Guid in database as char(32). Would that possible because of international website or different timezone can the character length go over size 32?

Answer (score 89):

The dashes are always in the same place, so no, it will not reduce the uniqueness.

```
System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
```

Will generate a GUID without dashes, as in this [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

The dashes are not part of the guid itself. They are just part of a common representation of guids. So the removal won't change the Guid value itself.